# Is there any direct function to put dataframe directly to mysql databse

Tags: mysql

please check this code i want to add this dataframe directly to my mysql database and this show error?

> (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL
> server host '1@localhost' (11003) (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)??

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String
import pandas as pd

 # Assuming df2 is your DataFrame with data
data = {'id': [23, 24, 2332, 434, 232, 121, 2434, 343],
    'name': ['who', 'who', 'you', 'you', 'you', 'me', 'me', 'why'],
    'salary': [200, 0, 0, 213232, 200, 2000, 2300, 2333]}

 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# SQLAlchemy engine
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database_name}")

# Define column data types
dtype = {'id': Integer(),
     'name': String(255),
     'salary': Integer()}
# Use the to_sql method to insert DataFrame into MySQL using SQLAlchemy
df2.to_sql('employee', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype=dtype)`
```

Comment: Do you have a mysql server runing on your machine?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your approach using `.to_sql()` is correct, but the issue appears to be in the engine / database connection of SQLAlchemy. As Jens pointed out, the (local) server might be offline, or your engine URL is incorrect. You can check this with `engine.url`. You also did not provide a port, this is generally required. The default port is :3306, in which case the passed url should be: `f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}:3306/{database_name}"`

Answer (score 0):

try creating a blank table if the 'employee' table does not exist yet.
then using the df.to_sql() code set if_exists='append'.

I hope this helps!